# 7G file in root directory

Tags: linux, files

A few minutes before I wondered why no upload to my server worked — the problem was: There is no free space left on the 15GB / partition. I found 2 files named "vx" (7GB) and "v"(2GB) in the root directory, but I have no idea where they come from and if they are important…

Do you know where they could have come from and if I can delete them?

The server is running some basic processes like php, mysql, webdav etc.
thx

Comment: Run the command `file vx`.  and `file x` to see what type of file they are.

Comment: btw can anyone explain why the qeustion has been voted down? Have I missed some netiquette or is it because of my dumbness (which I could understand ^^)

Comment: Delete them anyway.. If someone's dumb enough to leave them there, they deserve to lose them.

Comment: I suspect because your quest asking something that nobody else in the world could know.  If you don't know where your files came from, why should we know?  If you aren't sure what something is, delete it.  If it was important, then restore it from your backup.  (You **DO** make backups right?)

Comment: Umm… yes, now I see, it was very unclear, sorry for that ;)

Comment: To be fair I only knew the answer because I had just done it myself :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like someone was typing tar with the options in the wrong order

```
tar -czfv archive.tgz archive/
```

creates a "v" file for me (and no output) where you probably meant

```
tar -czvf archive.tgz archive/
```

You can try

```
 tar -tvzf my_tar.tar.gz >/dev/null
```

and see if you get a file listing to verify.